# Java Library to output to OpenGL (interactive) and SVG (for printing)

Tags: java, svg, shared-libraries, jogl, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a Java library that has multiple output backends:

- It should support OpenGL for interactive use (to get hardware acceleration)
- It should have SVG export - preferrably using CSS for that, to allow editing in e.g. inkscape - for a good print quality
- It must be cross-platform (Linux/Win/OSX)

Right now, I'm mostly using **Apache Batik**. It's quite nice: I can have listeners, use stylesheets, and export to various formats, including editable SVG. *And I need to be able to fine-tune the graphics for printing*. However, for some of my use cases it just gets *too slow*. The SVG XML DOM comes at a lot of overhead; it spends a lof of time checking CSS classes, checking for listeners, etc. - I need something faster.

I've been interested in **Cairo**, however it seems as if the GTK3-Cario + java-gnome toolchain is not available for Win32 yet.

**Clutter** is also promising, but it doesn't seem as if there are Java bindings, unfortunately. It uses OpenGL for 3D and Cairo for 2D afaict.

Do you know a library for interactive graphics with OpenGL that can alternatively export to editable SVG files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider QT-Jambi; (https://github.com/qtjambi/qtjambi). It's accelerated and supported on most platforms, including mobile.

Comment: I am a GTK supporter myself but from version 3... GTK-3 is doomed to be slow and stupidly complex.

Comment: It doesn't show any activity in 6 months now, no up to date examples either. Doesn't look mature enough for me, unfortunately.